# On Skyrim, after you cure Serana and killed Harkon and free'd Valerica, can you still obtain the power to become a vampire lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

The reason I ask is because Valerica won't offer it and I don't know if it's glitched or she doesn't offer it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no one left to give you the gift.  You sort of got rid of all the gifters.